# Multiple errors per field in Mongoose validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

Has anyone workaround for getting all errors per field in Mongoose validation? Right now, when some field has an error, validation for that field stops, because of that, you need to resubmit form to see next error.

This behaviour might be fixed in future (https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2612), but before that, I would love to see a workaround, which would let me to use `validation` method, for e.g.:

```
User.schema.path('hashed_password').validate(function (value) {
    if ( ! something)
        this.invalidate('password', 'Something is wrong with the password');
});
```

Note: Using `validation` method, I can bind error to any field, not just the one validated at the moment. Right now there is no plugin which would let me do that (I have tested **mongoose-validator-all** and **mongoose-validate-all** and those plugins are using different strategy).

Comment: Have you tried to issue all such xxxx.validate() calls, record failures then hold off to issue this.invalidate() until all calls are done ? ...